# How to get the structure of a neural network in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How to extract the structure of a neural network from an existing graph? That is, assuming a network exists in the current graph, I would like to have a dictionary that maps each variable to the variables it is connected to. Tensorboard somehow does this under the hood to visualize the graph but I am not able to deduce it from their code.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can save the model.[links](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#save_variables)
2. you can expore the model to *.pb.[links](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#manually_build_a_savedmodel)